# Microsoft Word component does not work

Tags: .net, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop, pia

I need to use a .NET application with Microsoft Office 2007.
The application works on my machine but not on a Windows server 2012 machine, because the Open() method does not work.

I made the following steps:

> 1) compile the application on my machine
>
> 2) install Microsoft Office system 2007 in the remote client machine
>
> 3) install the PIA component in the remote client machine
>
> 4) bring just the dll of my application in the proper folder of the
>   other machine

What's wrong with these steps?
After installing Office where can I find the `Microsoft.Office.Interop dll`?

Comment: Why do you want to use Ms Office on Server Side?

Comment: Because of client policy, any (free) other ideas? Thank you

Comment: Try `Spire.Xls`.For that add the reference `Spire.Xls`,which can be added to your project using Manage `Nuget Packages`.

Comment: You need to  either deploy the interop assembly, or, which is a simpler way, set the embed interop types entry in the assembly reference properties to true.